# How to make a fragment wait to the current location in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, location, kotlin-coroutines

I want a fragment to wait to the user's current location, then create the viewModel that gets inside the init block a list of data according to the coordinates that have been passed to the viewModel constructor.

I tried to solve this problem by writing a coroutine, but it hasn't been successful yet. The viewModel is being instantiated before the location is retrieved.

**OverviewFragment.kt**

```
class OverviewFragment: Fragment() {


   private var searchOptions: SearchOptions? = null
   private var radiusCenterPointLocation: Location? = null
   private val job = Job()
   private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + job)

   override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
       savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

       val binding: FragmentOverviewBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_overview, container, false)

       binding.lifecycleOwner = this

       try {
           searchOptions = OverviewFragmentArgs.fromBundle(arguments!!).searchOptions
       } catch (e: Exception) {
       }

       if (radiusCenterPointLocation == null ) {
           coroutineScope.launch {
               radiusCenterPointLocation =
                   async{ getCurrentLocation()}.await()
           }
       }

       Log.i("onCreateView", "We got location")

       val viewModelFactory = OverviewViewModelFactory(searchOptions, radiusCenterPointLocation)

       val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this,
           viewModelFactory).get(OverviewViewModel::class.java)

       binding.viewModel = viewModel
```

And the **getCurrentLocation()** function

```
suspend fun getCurrentLocation(): Location? {
        val fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context!!)
        return withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            val task = fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation
            while (!task.isSuccessful) {
                delay(1000)
            }
            Log.i("return location", "${task.result!!.latitude}")
            return@withContext task.result
        }
    }
```

This is what the log shows regarding the location:

```
2019-10-18 11:31:49.095 11304-11304/com.package I/onCreateView: We got location
2019-10-18 11:31:51.291 11304-11304/com.package I/return location: 44.4255631
```

So according to the logs, the location is returned after is needed for creating the viewModel. How can I make the code "wait" for the result of the getCurrentLocation() function?

Answer (score 1):

UI thread should not wait for anything. I mean, if there is no location available yet on UI progress bar should be shown or something like that.

Also, the idea behind MVVM (so the architecture introducing ViewModels) is that view reacts to state and both are kind of independent. So, your fragment should not call for location, it should only observe livedata containg that location.

So, I would suggest following:

```
Model:

class LocationModel {
    val locationData: MutableLiveData<Location> = MutableLiveData()

    init {
        getLocation()
    }

    fun getLocation() {
        ...
        locationData.set(position)
    }

    fun getLocationData(): LiveData<Location> { return locationData }
}

ViewModel:
// just "proxy" between Fragment, LocationModel and others Model

Fragment: 
class Fragment: Fragment() {
    fun onViewCreated() {
        viewModel.getLocationData().observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { location -> 
            if (location == null) {
                showProgress()
            } else {
                showLocation()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'am aware here of coroutines and other stuff, because your main problem is that you want to block UI thread until a potentially blocking operation will finish. It will end with ANR.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I've moved the location related code in the ViewModel and it works fine. It seems that I must be more of a purist if I want to build a MVVM app.